# Install jupyter lab extension without Conda

Tags: python, node.js, npm, conda, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install many jupyter lab extension and always receive this error:

> ValueError: Please install Node.js and npm before continuing installation. You may be able to install Node.js from your package manager, from conda, or directly from the Node.
> js website (https://nodejs.org).

After a little bit of digging, I find out that I need to have nodejs and npm. However, after success fully installed both of them through pip, I still cannot run `jupyter lab build`. Some people say it's because nodejs must be installed through conda for it to be working properly.

Does anyone have any idea how I can still have nodejs and npm working without having had to install Conda? I am running on Windows btw.

Comment: Extensions system was reworked in JupyterLab 3.0 and no longer requires nodejs/npm/jupyterlab build. Just upgrade to 3.0 and use `pip install` to install extensions.

Comment: After installing NodeJS, it's best to restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by:

1. Installing [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) on my machine (Windows).
2. Re-starting my computer.

After this, I was able to run `jupyter labextension install` without having `conda` installed.